# Lipschitz condition on $x*|y|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

The IVP $y'=x|y|$ is given along with the condition $y(1)=0$.
Upon checking the Lipschitz condition one gets,

> $|x|*||y_{2}|-|y_{1}||\le|x|*|y_{2}-y_{1}|$

Now, if I go locally around $x=1$, $|x|$ shall keep on increasing ahead of $x=1$.

So, as I see it, I will never get that fixed **L** in

> $||y_{2}|-|y_{1}||\le L|y_{2}-y_{1}|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall(x,y)$

to prove the IVP having a unique solution.

> > The answer in the book says that the IVP does have a unique solution around $x=1$.

Where am I wrong with my argument?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't around $x=1$ not mean for some neighborhood $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. If you just constrain $\epsilon\leq 1$, then $L=2$ works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an $L$ can be found.

There are 6 cases to check, but due to the symmetries of the problem this is can be reduced to just two case. I will show you those two cases, and leave it up to you to verify the rest.

**Case 1:** $0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2$ and $|y_1| \leq |y_2|$

We have
\begin{align*}
||y_2| - |y_1|| = |y_2 - y_1| = y_2 - y_1,
\end{align*}
and,
$$|y_2 - y_1| = y_2 - y_1.$$
Therefore, the constant $L = 1$ will suffice here.

**Case 2:** $y_1 \leq 0 \leq y_2$ and $|y_1| \leq |y_2|$
We have
$$||y_2| - |y_1|| = |y_2 + y_1| = y_2 + y_1,$$
and,
$$|y_2 - y_1| = y_2 - y_1 \geq y_2 + y_1.$$
Again, the constant $L=1$ is sufficient.

From here, all other case are symmetries of these first two cases.

I hope this answers your question. I am not entirely confident I correctly understood your problem.